# Could not find method getCompileConfiguration() for arguments[]

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

I'm getting the following error.

> Could not find method getCompileConfiguration() for arguments [] on
>   object of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: i am hybrid(IONIC 1) app developer i installed fcm,google analytics,and location plugins.I added  maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    } in build.gradle for plugin dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing similar issue and after spent some time over internet I found below solution.
If you are using latest version of google-services in build.gradle then following changes need to be done :-

1) In project level build.gradle

```
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                mavenLocal()
                maven {
                    url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                    name 'Google'
                }
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
            }
        }

        allprojects {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                mavenLocal()
                maven {
                    url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                    name 'Google'
                }
            }
        }
```

2) In App level build.gradle

```
android{
    //All other
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    }
        dependencies {
        // All other
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
        }
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

3) In gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Comment: I did all changes but getting error :-  Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :CordovaLib

Answer (score 1):

we had the same problem... solved by upgrading gradle in gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-bin.zip
```

and the gradle plugin in gradle.build

```
repositories {
    google()
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
}
```

Comment: I made same changes but it showing following error:- Error:Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :CordovaLib.