# Error:Could not find method getCompileConfiguration() for arguments [] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gradle, crash, android-studio-3.0

I' am working on **React Native** technology and everything was working fine until yesterday and today when I opened react-native project in the android studio it gave me this error:

> Error:Could not find method getCompileConfiguration() for arguments [] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

Please help me out with the best solution to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Hi we have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same issue here, I found a potential answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131089/could-not-find-method-getcompileconfiguration-for-arguments  but it didn't work for me as react-native-image picker is not compatible with latest gradle..

Answer (score 8):

I think this is due to `com.google.gms:google-services` released a new version that is not compatible with the gradle build tools, to fix it I changed `android/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  - classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+'
  - classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.+'
  + classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
  + classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
```

To use strict versions, as per the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Comment: just to add to this sometimes we may need to to change the build gradle to 2.3.3 and in our gradle wrapper properties to 4.1-all.zip